# Fetch user interests and likes from Facebook along with images using Facebook js SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am new for using Facebook API. I want to fetch Facebook logged in user's interests and likes with images.

```
<script>
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      authToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;//this comes back as expected
      testAPI();`
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Not authorized';
    }
  });
}

function testAPI() {
  FB.api( "me/likes", function( meResponse ){   
    meResponse.authToken = authToken;
    alert(meResponse.result);
  });
}
</script>
```

But it gives **undefined** when alert call.

Comment: Check the whole `response` object, it should contain an `error` object if `response.result` is returning **undefined**

Comment: No I have tried response object not giving any error

Answer (score 0):

You have a single upper quote char in your code after calling `testAPI();` Furthermore, I don't exaclty understand what the `meResponse.authToken = authToken;` should do (or why).

And, instead of `alert(meResponse.result);` you should do the following:

```
alert(typeof meresponse);
alert(JSON.stringify(meResponse));
```

AFAIK there's no `result` property.

Comment: how to get url of interest images using facebook js sdk.

Comment: What do you mean with "interest images"

Comment: i want to get images of movies,sports etc that i have liked in facebook.